# Can i specify multiple intervals using BETWEEN and IN clause in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I am querying some time-series data and would like to apply a query to multiple specified time intervals to get different rows for each interval.

Here is what I mean:
these are the time intervals (don't look at the null one, going to use `coalesce()`):
[image: intervals]

and would like to query my data like this:

```
select count(*) from time_series where time between [multiple_intervals_here]
```

the closest I've come to the solution is:

```
select count(*) from time_series where time (between x and y) or (between a and b)
```

but obviously, I cannot specify the intervals dynamically **and** would not get a row for each interval.

(I will apply some more aggregate functions to it, not just `count()`)

The end result would look like this:

[image: end result]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want to left join your table of intervals to your table of timepoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `t` CTE is a mimic of the list of intervals.

```sql
with t (id, time_start, time_stop) as
(
 values
 ('interval-A', '2022-05-26T10:00'::timestamp, '2022-05-26T12:00'::timestamp),
 ('interval-B', '2022-05-26T13:00', '2022-05-26T17:00')
)
select t.id, count(l.x) as "count", avg(l.x) as "avg" 
from t
cross join lateral 
(
 select x from the_table tt 
 where tt.start_time between t.time_start and t.time_stop
   and tt.end_time   between t.time_start and t.time_stop
) l
group by t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a separate query for each interval and union the results

```
select 'interval 1' as interval, count(*) from time_series where time between A and B
union
select 'interval 2' as interval, count(*) from time_series where time between C and D
union
select 'interval 3' as interval, count(*) from time_series where time between E and F
```